# How to concatenate the strings received from api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I want to highlight the words that are in the "highlight" elements in the "text" element sentence. I can successfully highlight one sentence but I'm not able to concatenate two or more sentences together. I'm only able to show one sentence and it's highlighted word with the code:

```
this.setState({
  text: result[0].text,
  highlight: result[0].highlight,
});
```

But not more than more sentence at once. I want to dynamically concatenate as many sentences as there are in the api with the highlighted words. I tried setting the state to `text: result[].text` and `highlight: result[].highlight` but it gave me errors. As you can see in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-cohen-j07q1), only when you do `result[0].text` or `result[1].text`, you get the different results but I want to concatenate all the sentences that are in the api dynamically supposing that I will have more sentences in the future.

The react code looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import "./App.css";

const stripChars = word => word.replace(/[\W_]+/g, "");

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    text: "The gun is a dangerous weapon, don't kill anyone",
    highlight: ["gun", "kill"]
    // text: "",
    // highlight: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ep1fh")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        this.setState({
          text: result[0].text,
          highlight: result[0].highlight
        });
      });
  }
  render() {
    const { text, highlight } = this.state;
    const words = text.split(" ");
    return (
      <div>
        {words.map((word, i) => (
          <span key={i}>
            <span
              className={highlight.includes(stripChars(word)) && "highlight"}
            >
              {word}
            </span>
            &nbsp;
          </span>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The CSS file:

```
.highlight{
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: If your API returns more than one element in the result, you have to iterate over the result array. Use a `for in` or `for of` loop for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate over your api results in order to concatenate them :

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ep1fh")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        let text = "";
        let highlight = [];
        for (const item of result) {
          text += item.text + '\n';
          highlight = [...highlight, ...item.highlight];
        }
        this.setState({
          text,
          highlight
        });
      });
  }
```

**Edit:** some code explanations

> `highlight = [...highlight, ...item.highlight];`

Yes, this is the array spread operator here to create a single array with all words to highlight. (For each loop iteration, it spreads all words from the actual item's highlights in the loop, and also spread the old ones);

You can also do it like this :

```
for (const word of item.highlight) {
  highlight.push(word);
}
```

> `let text = "";`
>    `let highlight = [];`

This is just variable init, these are new ones, I could name them differently (I should have named them `concatenatedTexts` and `concatenatedHighlights` to avoid confusion)

Yes, the state is erased, if you want to keep your initial state and concatenate it too you can change `setState` like this :

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  text: prevState.text + "\n" + text,
  highlight: [...prevState.highlight, ...highlight]
}));
```

Comment: this worked.. thanks. could you also please help me understand it a little

Comment: This a just a loop to iterate the results array and pick each text and highlight from the array objects, can you tell me which part you don't understand ?

Comment: why did you take let text and let highlight again? because of taking it again, the initial states gets erased right? becuase the first sentence should appear twice as I have set it as initially in the state, and it's again the first element in the api.
also is this spread operator that you are using? highlight = [...highlight, ...item.highlight];

Comment: thanks for the explanation.. could I use drop down menu on the highlighted word? this is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/utmkr2ew... I was wondering where would I write the onclick method in a react js file as written in the jsfiddle demo

Comment: @MLnewb You can conditionnally render a `<select>` if the word is highlight (like you do in className), you may want create a new question for this because it'll be hard to help you in comments like that.

Comment: okay, i will create a new question for that.. Btw "\n" isn't working in your solution. it's showing in the same line instead of a new line.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.Map` and `join()` in your api call for iterate and flat the array :

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ep1fh")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => {
        let texts = result
          .map((el, i) => {
            return el.text;
          })
          .join("");
        let highlights = result
          .map((el, i) => {
            return el.highlight;
          })
          .join("").split(",");
        console.log(highlights);
        this.setState({
          text: texts,
          highlight: highlights
        });
      });
  }
```

[result](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-leaf-1l4fl)

Comment: Use `join('');` otherwise you will get extra comma between the vales.

Comment: why is it even highlighting 'a' in the first sentence

Comment: @MLnewb, because you are using includes that needs an array as argument, check updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the central part of your code with something similar to this should fix it:

```
fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ep1fh")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(result => {
    let text = '';
    let highlights = [];

    // This will iterate over every entry in your result
    for(const r of result) {
      // The method will be executed for every entry, called r
      text += r.text;
      highlights.push(...r.highlight);
    }

    this.setState({
      text: text,
      highlight: highlights
    });
  });
}
```

This is very similar to @Dyo's approach, but it should be a little bit more efficient. He creates a new copy of the whole highlight array plus the entries to add in each iteration, while in this example, we use the `Array.push` method. This only adds the new values while not duplicating the original values.

Comment: This will overwrite the value and state will have last one.

Comment: @jcubic I see. I thought, that `setState` is a method to append the string to the existing texts. In this case, you have to do the concatenation right there in this method. I've edited it slightly, so it should work now.

Comment: There are no any edits you need to use `text: this.state.text + r.text`

Comment: @jcubic Sorry, I've posted before editing. The edit should be visible now.

Comment: And now the code will create from input `['foo', 'bar']` -> `[['f', 'o', 'o'], ['b', 'a', 'r']]` if you spread the string you will get array of characters you you push that into antoher array. Please don't use something if you don't know how it works.

Comment: @jcubic Sorry, I thought, that `text` is an array as well.

Comment: OP use it as value `this.setState({
          text: result[0].text,
          highlight: result[0].highlight
        });` and text usually mean string.